# Вызов метода из SOAP веб-сервиса в Java

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

Необходимо получить курс валют по отношению к рублю для определенной страны, посредством вот [этого](http://www.cbr.ru/DailyInfoWebServ/DailyInfo.asmx?op=GetCursOnDate) метода.

Проблема в том, чтобы его вызвать и получить из него данные в приемлемом формате. Если использую `wsimport` и генерирую необходимые классы, то возникает вопрос. Как получить необходимые данные в удобной форме?

Из описания сервиса:

`GetCursOnDate(On_date)` - получение курсов валют на определенную дату (ежедневные курсы валют)

`GetSeldCursOnDate` - (ежемесячные курсы валют)

Аргументы:

`On_date` - дата запроса для курсов, формат - `System.DateTime`

Результат:

XML документ в формате `System.Data.Dataset`, содержащий таблицу `[ValuteCursOnDate]`

Однако, насколько я понял, это не действительно для сгенерированных классов и получение необходимых данных я должен использовать что-то вроде:

```
public GetCursOnDateResponse.GetCursOnDateResult CursOnDate(XMLGregorianCalendar date) {
    DailyInfo dailyInfo = new DailyInfo();
    DailyInfoSoap dailyInfoSoap = dailyInfo.getDailyInfoSoap();
    GetCursOnDateResponse.GetCursOnDateResult cursOnDate = dailyInfoSoap.getCursOnDate(date);
    return cursOnDate;
```

Также там имеются классы `GetCursOnDateXMLResponse` и `GetCursOnDateXMLResult`. 
Однако мне не совсем понятно, что я в итоге получаю и как это преобразовать в нормальный вид.

Прошу направить меня туда, где вообще стоит копать и что изучить для решения подобного рода задач, так как многочасовой заплыв в google дал гору разномастной информации, однако понимания это не дало. Насколько я понял, то если использовать код выше, то возвращается курс валют в формате датасета, если использовать методы с XML, то в формате XML?

Кроме того, по ссылке выше, где описывается метод `GetCursOnDate` есть примеры SOAP `request` и `response` для этого метода. Для чего они нужны? Не проще ли вызвать метод напрямую через SOAP или вообще как это можно сделать? 
Подтолкните в правильном направлении.

Answer (score 1):

Ты всё правильно сделал, но тебе не хватило терпения. Взгляни на пример ответа от данного сервиса.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetCursOnDateResponse xmlns="http://web.cbr.ru/">
            <GetCursOnDateResult>
                <xs:schema id="ValuteData" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop">
                    <xs:element name="ValuteData" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true" msprop:OnDate="20150924">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:element name="ValuteCursOnDate">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element name="Vname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="Vnom" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="Vcurs" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="Vcode" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="VchCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                        </xs:sequence>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:choice>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:schema>
                <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
                    <ValuteData xmlns="">
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                            <Vname>Австралийский доллар                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          </Vname>
                            <Vnom>1</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>46.5061</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>36</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>AUD</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
                            <Vname>Азербайджанский манат                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         </Vname>
                            <Vnom>1</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>62.9862</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>944</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>AZN</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
                            <Vname>Фунт стерлингов Соединенного королевства                                                                                                                                                                                                                      </Vname>
                            <Vnom>1</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>101.3465</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>826</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>GBP</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate4" msdata:rowOrder="3">
                            <Vname>Армянский драм                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                </Vname>
                            <Vnom>100</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>13.9364</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>51</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>AMD</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate5" msdata:rowOrder="4">
                            <Vname>Белорусский рубль                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             </Vname>
                            <Vnom>10000</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>37.5340</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>974</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>BYR</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate6" msdata:rowOrder="5">
                            <Vname>Болгарский лев                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                </Vname>
                            <Vnom>1</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>37.5212</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>975</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>BGN</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate7" msdata:rowOrder="6">
                            <Vname>Бразильский реал                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              </Vname>
                            <Vnom>1</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>16.3145</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>986</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>BRL</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate8" msdata:rowOrder="7">
                            <Vname>Венгерский форинт                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             </Vname>
                            <Vnom>100</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>23.6893</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>348</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>HUF</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate9" msdata:rowOrder="8">
                            <Vname>Датская крона                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 </Vname>
                            <Vnom>10</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>98.3924</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>208</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>DKK</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate10" msdata:rowOrder="9">
                            <Vname>Доллар США                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    </Vname>
                            <Vnom>1</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>66.0410</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>840</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>USD</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate11" msdata:rowOrder="10">
                            <Vname>Евро                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          </Vname>
                            <Vnom>1</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>73.5367</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>978</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>EUR</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate12" msdata:rowOrder="11">
                            <Vname>Индийская рупия                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               </Vname>
                            <Vnom>10</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>10.0077</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>356</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>INR</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate13" msdata:rowOrder="12">
                            <Vname>Казахстанский тенге                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           </Vname>
                            <Vnom>100</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>24.6422</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>398</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>KZT</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate14" msdata:rowOrder="13">
                            <Vname>Канадский доллар                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              </Vname>
                            <Vnom>1</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>49.7447</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>124</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>CAD</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate15" msdata:rowOrder="14">
                            <Vname>Киргизский сом                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                </Vname>
                            <Vnom>100</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>93.5094</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>417</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>KGS</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate16" msdata:rowOrder="15">
                            <Vname>Китайский юань                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                </Vname>
                            <Vnom>1</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>10.3449</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>156</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>CNY</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate17" msdata:rowOrder="16">
                            <Vname>Молдавский лей                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                </Vname>
                            <Vnom>10</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>33.2031</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>498</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>MDL</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate18" msdata:rowOrder="17">
                            <Vname>Норвежская крона                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              </Vname>
                            <Vnom>10</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>79.6769</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>578</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>NOK</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate19" msdata:rowOrder="18">
                            <Vname>Польский злотый                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               </Vname>
                            <Vnom>1</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>17.4633</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>985</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>PLN</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate20" msdata:rowOrder="19">
                            <Vname>Румынский лей                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 </Vname>
                            <Vnom>1</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>16.6099</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>946</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>RON</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate21" msdata:rowOrder="20">
                            <Vname>СДР (специальные права заимствования)                                                                                                                                                                                                                         </Vname>
                            <Vnom>1</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>92.7414</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>960</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>XDR</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate22" msdata:rowOrder="21">
                            <Vname>Сингапурский доллар                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           </Vname>
                            <Vnom>1</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>46.4227</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>702</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>SGD</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate23" msdata:rowOrder="22">
                            <Vname>Таджикский сомони                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             </Vname>
                            <Vnom>1</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>10.2924</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>972</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>TJS</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate24" msdata:rowOrder="23">
                            <Vname>Турецкая лира                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 </Vname>
                            <Vnom>1</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>21.8072</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>949</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>TRY</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate25" msdata:rowOrder="24">
                            <Vname>Новый туркменский манат                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       </Vname>
                            <Vnom>1</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>18.8689</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>934</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>TMT</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate26" msdata:rowOrder="25">
                            <Vname>Узбекский сум                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 </Vname>
                            <Vnom>1000</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>25.2065</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>860</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>UZS</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate27" msdata:rowOrder="26">
                            <Vname>Украинская гривна                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             </Vname>
                            <Vnom>10</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>30.6455</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>980</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>UAH</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate28" msdata:rowOrder="27">
                            <Vname>Чешская крона                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 </Vname>
                            <Vnom>10</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>27.0965</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>203</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>CZK</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate29" msdata:rowOrder="28">
                            <Vname>Шведская крона                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                </Vname>
                            <Vnom>10</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>78.4829</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>752</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>SEK</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate30" msdata:rowOrder="29">
                            <Vname>Швейцарский франк                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             </Vname>
                            <Vnom>1</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>67.5542</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>756</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>CHF</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate31" msdata:rowOrder="30">
                            <Vname>Южноафриканский рэнд                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          </Vname>
                            <Vnom>10</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>48.2262</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>710</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>ZAR</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate32" msdata:rowOrder="31">
                            <Vname>Вон Республики Корея                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          </Vname>
                            <Vnom>1000</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>55.5368</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>410</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>KRW</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                        <ValuteCursOnDate diffgr:id="ValuteCursOnDate33" msdata:rowOrder="32">
                            <Vname>Японская иена                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 </Vname>
                            <Vnom>100</Vnom>
                            <Vcurs>54.9449</Vcurs>
                            <Vcode>392</Vcode>
                            <VchCode>JPY</VchCode>
                        </ValuteCursOnDate>
                    </ValuteData>
                </diffgr:diffgram>
            </GetCursOnDateResult>
        </GetCursOnDateResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Для того, чтобы добраться до ответа нужно пройти дальше. Но тут влетает одна проблема. Согласно wsdl ответ будет такого типа:

```
<s:element name="GetCursOnDateResponse">
 <s:complexType>
  <s:sequence>
   <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetCursOnDateResult">
    <s:complexType>
     <s:sequence>
      <s:element ref="s:schema"/>
      <s:any/>
     </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
   </s:element>
  </s:sequence>
 </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

пакостный `<s:any/>` говорит, что элемент может быть любым. В данном случае он `<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">`. Обрати внимание на пространство имён `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1`. Оно не определено в схеме http://www.cbr.ru/DailyInfoWebServ/DailyInfo.asmx?WSDL. Поэтому когда ты сгенерируешь java-классы из wsdl, то в них не будет отражения для класса-ответа. Согласно спецификации, в этом случае jaxb-маршаллер должен будет оставить его в [Element](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html). Итого дальше делаешь:

```
org.w3c.dom.Element el=(org.w3c.dom.Element)cursOnDate.getAny();
```

и работаешь с `el`.

---

На всякий случай держи пример запроса с http-заголовками (обрати внимание на нестандартны заголовок "SoapAction")

```
POST http://www.cbr.ru/DailyInfoWebServ/DailyInfo.asmx?op=GetCursOnDate
SOAPAction: http://web.cbr.ru/GetCursOnDate
Content-Type: text/xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetCursOnDate xmlns="http://web.cbr.ru/">
      <On_date>2015-09-24</On_date>
    </GetCursOnDate>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```